# Sum of all minimal right ideal of simple artinian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a simple right artinian ring (not necessarily with unity). 
I want to show:

> If $R$ is sum of all minimal right ideals of $R$,then $R$ is sum of finitely many minimal right ideals of $R$

I know if $R$ is a right northerian ring, we can construct an infiniet ascending chain $A_1 \subseteq A_1+A_2 \subseteq A_1+A_2+A_3 \subseteq ...$ which each $A_i$ is minimal right ideal of R.Since
$R$ is artinian we have $A_1+A_2+...+A_n=A_1+A_2+...+A_m$ for some integer n and $ \forall$ m $\ge$ n.
Hence $A_1+A_2+...+A_n=R$.
(Does my prove has any wrong?)

But for $R$ is a artinian ring,I have no idea to proof it.

Comment: As long as a ring $R$ has a multiplicative identity, if a sum of right ideals equals $R$, a sum of finitely many of those right ideals equals $R$.

Comment: Ring $R$ in my post is not necessarily with unit.

Comment: For the descending chain, consider $A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + ... \supseteq A_2 + A_3 + A_4 + ... \supseteq A_3 + A_4 + A_5 + ... \supseteq ...$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Since $R$ is a right artinian ring, we have $A_n+A_{n+1}+...=A_m+A_{m+1}+...$ for some interger n and $\forall$ m with m $\ge$ n.
What is next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just attempt to build an infinite direct sum of minimal right ideals, and note that it cannot succeed if $R_R$ is to be Artinian.

Because $R_R$ is Artinian, you know the right socle (the sum of minimal right ideals, itself an ideal) is nonzero and therefore must be all of $R$ (since $R$ is simple.)

Suppose $R_R$ isn't a finite sum of minimal right ideals. There exists a minimal right ideal $A_0$ (because $R_R$ is Artinian).  Since $A_0\neq R$, there's another simple right ideal $A_1$ not contained in $A_0$.  Since $A_0\oplus A_1\neq R$, there exists a third minimal right ideal $A_2$ not contained in this direct sum.  Inductively, you have $\bigoplus_{i=0}^n A_i$ for each natural number $n$, and you can see that $B=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty A_i=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \bigoplus_{i=0}^n A_i$ is a submodule of $R_R$.

But obviously $B$ poses problems for $R_R$ being right Artinian: it clearly contains infinite descending chains.

So, the assumption that $R_R$ cannot be a finite sum of minimal right ideals is an absurdity, and we know the opposite is true.

---

It is fascinating to me (also previously mentioned in the comments) that in the case when $R$ has an identity 1, it gives the ring a sort of compactness, because we get the following version of the proposition that doesn't need simplicity or chain conditions:

> If $R$ is a ring with identity such that $\sum_{i\in I} A_i=R$ for some collection of right ideals $A_i$, then $\sum_{i\in F} A_i=R$ for some finite subset $F$ of $I$.

The argument is easy, of course: $1\in \sum_{i\in F} A_i$ for some finite subset $F$, and from there it follows that $R=1\cdot R\subseteq \sum_{i\in F} A_i$

Comment: Actually, we have $B=R$.And the infinite descending chain is $B \supseteq  \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty A_i \supseteq \bigoplus_{i=2}^\infty A_i \supseteq ...$.
Did I get that right?

Comment: @Lee Yes, on both counts, I believe.

Comment: Why $1\in \sum_{i\in F} A_i$ for some finite subset $F$?

Comment: @Lee An element of the sum is, by definition, a sum of finitely many nonzero elements of the $A_i$'s

Comment: But you assume that $R = \sum_{i\in I} A_i$, so $1\in \sum_{i\in I} A_i$ ,why 1 must in $\sum_{i\in F} A_i$ for some finite subset $F$

Comment: `An element of the sum is, by definition, a sum of finitely many nonzero elements of the $A_i$'s`. In particular, you can do that for the element **1**. Therefore it is also in the sum just over the finite subset that it is nonzero on.

Comment: Thank you!I know what your mean.You help me a lot!

Comment: I have a new question.Why the descending chain is infinitely?It mean $\bigoplus_{i=n}^\infty A_n \supset \bigoplus_{i=n+1}^\infty A_{n+1} \forall$ integer n. How to show it?

Comment: Obviously the thing on the left contains $A_n$ whereas the thing on the right does not. What more is there to say?

Comment: If $An \subseteq \bigoplus_{i=n+1}^\infty A_i$, then $\bigoplus_{i=n}^\infty A_i =\bigoplus_{i=n+1}^\infty A_i$

Comment: Does this make it easier?
$A_0\oplus A_1\oplus A_2\oplus\cdots \supset \{0\}\oplus A_1\oplus A_2\oplus\cdots \supset \{0\}\oplus \{0\}\oplus A_2\oplus\cdots \supset \ldots$

Comment: Thank you.I think I misunderstood the mean of direct sum.